# How to create a run-time method proxy with ByteBuddy

Tags: java, proxy, byte-buddy

I'm currently trying to create a run-time method proxy with ByteBuddy but fail to do so. The method I'm trying to proxy is a part of a different plugin for the same program (The project I'm working on is also a plugin and I can control the load order) and the change has to affect all instances of that class. Basically my goal with this proxy is to perform an If-check before calling the super method (or not depending on the check result).

I read a bunch of posts here and on GitHub but couldn't find a working solution yet. The only thing I got to work is overriding the super method completely by redefining it like this:

```
ByteBuddyAgent.install();
new ByteBuddy()
  .redefine(Foo.class)
  .method(named("bar").and(takesArguments(String.class, float.class, Integer.class)))
  .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(Interceptor.class))
  .make()
  .load(Foo.class.getClassLoader(), ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent());

public class Interceptor {
   @RuntimeType
   public static void intercept(@AllArguments Object[] allArguments) {
     System.out.println("Intercepted");
   }
}
```

This however doesn't allow me to call the super method from inside the interceptor because it gets lost when I redefine it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are redefining a class, you are affecting all instances. For a proxy, you normally only want to subclass.

If you want that, you would need to use rebase. Typically while using a Java agent. Have a look at AgentBuilder which you can add to the JVM.